# Python: prime test

Tags: python

I am writing a code to determine if a number is prime. This is what I've gathered so far:

```
def isprime(p):
'''check if integer p is a prime'''
# make sure n is a positive integer
p = abs(int(p))
# 0 and 1 are not primes
if n < 2:
    return False
# 2 is the only even prime number
if n = 2: 
    return True    
# all other even numbers are not primes
if not p & 1: 
    return False
# for all odd numbers
for x in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
    if n % x == 0:
        return False
return True
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: 1. Please fix your indentation. 2. The posted code will throw an error as `make` is not defined (I think that line was meant to be a comment). 3. What is the actual question? 4. What is the observed result, and how does it diverge from the expected? 5. `if n = 2:` will give you an error. Please post the actual code that you are using

Comment: Please make your code actually valid code—proper indentation, comments commented, etc.

Comment: Other than indentation and comment problems, the only obvious error is that `n = 2` is an assignment, not a comparison, so you can't put it in an `if` statement, and wouldn't want to if you could.

Comment: Oh, also, at some point you switch your variable name from `p` to `n`. You obviously need to use the same name for the same variable each time it appears; the interpreter can't read your mind. But if I fix that problem, the syntax error from the last comment, and the indentation and comment errors, your code appears to work just fine. At least it gives the right answers for everything from 0 to 20.

Comment: How many people need to check and find prime numbers by Python. That is an invasion on SO!!!!! Please ask to your teacher to change the assignments!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're tring to use the trivial (aka slow) method of computing primes: for a prime candidate p, try dividing all integers from 2 to floor(sqrt(p)).

```
eps = 1e-9
def isprime(p):
    int_p = int(p)
    # only integers are prime, accounting for floating point rounding error
    if abs(int_p - p) < eps:
        return False
    else:
        # a number is prime only if it cannot be evenly divided
        # by all prime factors lower than the number
        return all(p % i != 0 for i in xrange(2, int(p**0.5)+1))
```

The reason why you're wanting to only check odd numbers from 3 through sqrt(p) is probably because you know all even numbers greater than 2 are not prime. You can do better than eliminate just the even numbers from this check... You only need to check prime numbers from 2 through sqrt(p). If you happen to be calling `isprime` multiple times, you can build up a cache of these primes. There are even more efficient prime algorithms, depending on the problem that you're trying to solve (Are you trying to find all primes from a lower bound to an upper bound? Are you trying to find the quantity of primes? Are you trying to find any prime?)